# display all assertions in View Result Tree

Tags: jmeter

Actually i am creating a test plan using jmeter.In that test plan i have put 
many assertions like response assertion,xpath assertion and html assertion.
Now i want to show all assertion result in a single view result tree along with other results...for that i am using the custom code..but its not working.its showing only one assertion result that is last assertion result.so please tell how can i show all assertion in same result tree.My code is

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;



AssertionResult[] results = sampleResult.getAssertionResults() ;

for(int i =0,j=1 ; i<results.length;i++) {
    AssertionResult result = results[i];
                             if(result.isFailure()  || result.isError()) {
        vars.put("assertionResult_" +j, result.getFailureMessage());
        j++;
                             }
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on answers, if OK it should be accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

There is an Out Of The Box component to do this called [Assertion Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Assertion_Results)

Find a tutorial on assertions showing it at:

- http://www.guru99.com/assertions-in-jmeter.html